# Laravel 5.3 change request from api in view

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have a problem with Ajax and I don't know how to deal with it. I have a controller where is get response from external API. In this controller are passing variables to API request. The result is passing to a view. On this view i have drop down list with currency's. I want when user select another currency the new request will be send to API and generate new view.

Below is file and code.

web.php

```
Route::get('/currency', 'HomeController@getCurrency');
Route::post('/currency', 'HomeController@getCurrency');
```

I have a view:

```
@extends('layouts.app') @section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Currency</div>

                <div class="panel-body">

                {!! Form::open(array('url' => '/currency','method' =>'post')) !!}
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <select name="currency" id="currencyNameA">
                 @foreach($currency_table_A->rates as $rows)

                 <option value="{{ $rows->code }}">{{ $rows->currency }}</option>

                @endforeach
                </select>
                {!! Form::close() !!}

                    <br />

                <h2><div class="currency">
                currency {{$currency->currency}} {{ $currency->rates[0]->mid}} last update was {{ $currency->rates[0]->effectiveDate }}
                </div>
                </h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

And a controller:

```
 public function getCurrency(Request $request)
     {       

          $client = new GuzzleHttpClient(['base_uri' => 'http://api.nbp.pl/api/'],['headers'=>['content-type'=>
 'application/json']]);

             //Table for dropdown list Begin
             $table_response = $client->request('GET','exchangerates/tables/a');
             $currency_table_A =  json_decode($table_response->getBody());
             $currency_table_A = $currency_table_A[0];
             //Table for dropdown list End

         if($request->ajax() && $request->isMethod('post')){
             $cur = $request->input('currency'); //get currency from post
         }else{
             $cur = 'EUR';
         }  

     // Send a request to External API
     $response = $client->request('GET', 'exchangerates/rates/a/'.$cur);

     //Antwser from External API
     $currency =  json_decode($response->getBody());


   if($request->ajax() && $request->isMethod('post')){
        //In Debug bar i get reply form API but my View is not change
        Debugbar::info($currency);
        return response()->json(view('curentCurrency', compact('currency','currency_table_A'))->render());
    }else{
        return view('curentCurrency', compact('currency','currency_table_A'));
    }
    }
```

Script.js

```
$('#currencyNameA').change(function() {
    $.ajax({
    type:'post',
     dataType: 'json',
     headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
     url: '/currency',
      data:  { currency : $('#currencyNameA').val()},
   success: function(data){  
   }
  });
});
```

I need to pass a new answer to a View when was select new currency in drop list. When page is loaded first time i need to get basic value in USD when someone change from drop down list the currency result should change for that user choose.

Comment: Are you getting an error or anything with your code? What part of it isn't working. You've told us what you want to do, but not the part that isn't working specifically. Unless i missed it

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: No I don' t get an error.

Comment: After select new currency and pass it to a controller by ajax nothing change on a view.